# How to group by/ count an SQL join including threee tables

Tags: sql, join, group-by

I'd kindly want to ask for help regarding the following problem I came across in my project:
I have the following three tables:

1. manual m
2. author a
3. entity e

If I join them with:

```
select e.name, a.name
from manual m
join 
author a
on a.id = m.f_id
join 
entity e
on e.id = m.e_id
```

I get:

```
e.NAME              a.name
Daniel, Marcus  Komponist
Abene, Michael  Instrumentierung
Abene, Michael  Komponist
Abene, Michael  Bearbeiter
Abene, Michael  Komponist
```

I'd now would like to count how much a certain a.name is used for a e.name.
Applying this to the following example: I need something like this:

```
e.NAME              a.name                Count
Daniel, Marcus  Komponist                 1
Abene, Michael  Instrumentierung          1
Abene, Michael  Komponist                 2
Abene, Michael  Bearbeiter                1
```

I now have now idea how I have to count and group this...
Any kind of help is highly appreciated!
Thank you already in advance for your hints.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT    e.name, 
          a.name,
          COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM      manual m
          join author a
              on a.id = m.f_id
          join entity e
              on e.id = m.e_id
GROUP BY  e.name, 
          a.name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select e.name, a.name, count(*)
   from manual m
join 
   author a
   on a.id = m.f_id
join 
   entity e
   on e.id = m.e_id
group by e.name, a.name
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to `GROUP BY` both name columns and `COUNT()` `e.name`

```
SELECT e.name, a.name, COUNT(e.name) AS total
FROM manual m 
JOIN author a
ON a.id = m.f_id
JOIN entity e
ON e.id = m.e_id
GROUP BY e.name, a.name
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer.
Different answers helped me a lot to understand that stuff!